# How to change printer paper size to A6 or custom paper size in SAP Crystal reports?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I'm making report of custom paper size to be printed through C# windows forms application using SAP Crystal report.

While setting printer options by code in C# before printing, I don't find a way to set custom paper size within Crystal report code.

```
rpt.PrintOptions.PaperSize =CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize.PaperA5 ;
```

I wonder if there is there is a way to set custom paper size in print options like

```
rpt.PrintOptions.PaperSize =CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize.myCustomSize;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- From printer preferences in control panel > create custom paper size that you need
- From crystal report > Rt. Click > Design > Page Setup  From page options >
  Uncheck Dissociate formating page size and printer page size > choose
  custom paper size
- Don't modify printer page size using code
- Finally it would work without problems